# Subtract inside console.log in javascipt

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am new to JavaScript and while learning I came across the problem.

Question i have is :

> Using prompt get the year the user was born and if the user is 18 or
> above allow the user to drive if not tell the user to wait a certain
> amount of years.

and answer i need is

> Enter birth year: 1995 You are 25. You are old enough to drive
>
> Enter birth year: 2005 You are 15. You will be allowed to drive after
> 3 years.

Using below code I am doing it but only problem is i don't know how to get you will be allowed after result inside console.log

```
let bornIn = prompt("Enter Your Birth Year")
let now = new Date()
let yourAge = now.getFullYear() - bornIn

yourAge >= 21
    ? console.log(`You are ${yourAge}. You are old enough to drive`)
    : console.log(`You are ${yourAge}. You will need`)
```

I know my code is not perfect cause i am new to javascript.

Comment: Use `if else` to do it?

Comment: `You will be allowed to drive after ${18-yourAge} years`. Also, the condition should be `yourAge >= 18`

Answer (score 3):

You can do math inside [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
let bornIn = prompt("Enter Your Birth Year")
let now = new Date()
let yourAge = now.getFullYear() - bornIn

yourAge >= 18
    ? console.log(`You are ${yourAge}. You are old enough to drive`)
    : console.log(`You are ${yourAge}. You will be allowed to drive after ${18-yourAge} years.`)
```

Note you should be comparing `yourAge` with `18`, not `21`.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped and yes i know its an example.